# Как при изменении select изменить option'ы в другом select

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Есть два селекта:

```
    <select name="group" id="group">
    <option value="группа1" selected>группа1</option>
    <option value="группа2">группа2</option>
    ...
</select>

<select name="monter" id="monter">
    <option value="монтер_из_первой_группы1">монтер_из_первой_группы1</option>
    <option value="монтер_из_первой_группы2">монтер_из_первой_группы2</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Есть скрипт к которому можно обратиться GET запросом с названием группы, и который вернет список оптионов для данной группы. Вопрос! Как сделать что бы при изменении значения первого селекта подгрузить другие оптионы во второй при помощи jquery. javascript не знаю, знаю только html и php.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#group').on({
    change: function() {
        $.get('url', {data: 'getGroupName'}, function(result) {
            $('#monster').html(result);
        });
    }
});
```

php file:

```
if(isset($_GET['data'])) {
    if($_GET['data'] == 'getGroupName') {
        echo 'нужные оптионы';
    }
}
```